# How to set window's position in a relative way

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

There's a problem with the window widget. Is there a way to set window's position

without setting the absolute position?

for example:

I want to set the window pop-up to the bottom right corner of the browser.

Now I use setleft and setright (at 1000,800), but the window still at (1000,800)

when i minimized the browser's window.

So, the question is, is there a way to set the pop-up window in a relative way,

can still to the bottom right corner of the browser even when i minimized the browser's

window??

Thanks!!